# Maven Dependency changes commons-io version

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

first time asking. Sorry if I write weird but English is not my first language.

I have a maven dependency in my maven project for an external API. The thing is, that this dependency changes my common-io. From 2.8 to 2.2.

I would like to prevent this because affects one class of my project and I am not the only one working in it. Also, it could affect to future coding.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Add the dependency to common-io directly to your pom file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If commons-io is already provide by your pom and is newer than the version brought by the dependent you could exclude commons-io from this dependency :

```
<project>   
  ...   
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>your dependency-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

More details [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, in the end I put directly de dependency in my pom but I didn't know that you could exclude from a dependency. Good to know.